# Refile Metadata for Multiple Attachments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, nested-attributes, ruby-on-rails-5, refile

Using the refile gem, I want to save filenames for multiple uploads.  I've opened an issue on github [here](https://github.com/refile/refile/issues/497), but want to reach out to SO also. It's actually noted [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32507011/nested-attributes-of-uploaded-image-not-being-saved) also.

Following the readme, I've applied the correct strong_params, I can see they're permitted in the log, but the don't write to db.

A `:story` `accepts_attachments_for :documents`, and I have my metadata set up correctly for `Documents` class.

When I submit, nothing is rejected--I can see in the log that params are accepted, but the metadata (filename, etc) is not saved.

Where do I start?

### Source:

```
class Attachment < ApplicationRecord
  attachment :file
end

class Problem < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :attachments, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_attachments_for :attachments, append: true, attachment: :file
end
```

and controller params:

```
def mp_problem_params
  params.require(:problem).permit(:title, attachments_files: [])
end
```

My Attachment.rb columns:

```
=> ["id",
 "attachment_filename",
 "knowledge_id",
 "attachment_size",
 "content_type",
 "created_at",
 "updated_at",
 "file_id"]
```

Comment: Please  include the source code for the models and the controllers for better understanding.

Comment: @Dharam, does that help? It's pretty straight forward. Based on the links I provided, my issue is same.

Comment: Without knowing how your database is set up....

You have has_many :attachments. So in your params you should need something like 

params.require(:job_posting).permit(:title, document_attributes: [:filename, :id]

Comment: @DottedT what if the array is hashes? I thought declaring an empty array allowed all fields. I've also tried using '.permit!' Which hasn't worked.

Comment: Declaring an empty array in require defeats the purpose of it.  Require is there expressly to make you be specific about what is and is not allowed.

As for "what if the array is hashes", Parameters are sent as a hash so I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @DottedT, sorry I realize the hashes part was poorly phrased. The array for `document_attributes` is an array of hashes (since we're inputting multiple attributes). Can you confirm this works? I know it _should_, but I think I've tried this. I'll confirm as soon as I can.

Comment: @DottedT, just tried your recommendation (which I agree, makes sense), but explicitly calling `:id, :filename` prevents Refile from saving anything at all.

Comment: What I gave was just an example as I'm just guessing on what you're trying to save to the database for documents and/or story or attachments. I'm also guessing at how the form is constructed. The point is that it seems you're trying to use a controller to save to a has_many related model.  You'll also need to use accepts_nested_attributes_for. Have a look at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Could you provide the `attachments` table schema?

Comment: @Dharam, updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [refile documentation](https://github.com/refile/refile), metadata is stored on the object/model that you have setup to have `attachment`. In your case, `Attachment` model. It also expects certain columns to be present in order to store the metadata. Based on your `attachment` model:

```
class Attachment < ApplicationRecord
  attachment :file
end
```

Then you have to have the following columns present in the `attachments` table:

```
file_filename
file_size
file_content_type
```

If you add those columns to the `attachments` table then the metadata of the file will get stored.

Comment: Feel like a total idiot for not getting this...Thanks!